# How to add a value to all elements of a sliced 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, tkinter

My Code:

```
img = np.asarray(ibuffer).copy()
imgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
imgb[:,:,0] += bvalue
imgb = cv2.cvtColor(imgb,cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
photo = Image.fromarray(imgb)
photo = resize(photo)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
canvas.photo = photo
canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image = photo)
```

I need to add the value of 'bvalue' variable to all the elements of the 1st dimension the imgb(3D numpy array). When I try this, I get the following error message:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\asaru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1884, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "e:\My Files\Project\Image Editor\Image Editor\test.py", line 134, in bright

```
imgb[:,:,0] += bvalue
```

numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('<U3') to dtype('uint8') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Comment: Please make the code reproducible by creating some dummy random variables that causes the same error. We likely need to be able to run the code. Take look at the guidelines for asking a question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're allowed to add ints to numpy.uint8. If you cast your bvalue to an int (and assuming that bvalue is something that can be cast to an int) then your code should work.

```py
lab[:,:,0] += int(50.0)
```

The line above works for brightening the image. Be careful, since the channel is a uint8, it'll overflow if it goes over 255. If you go above that it'll wrap back around and continue on (255 + 11 = 10).

Answer (score 0):

Check [Numpy Dtypes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). Your variable `bvalue` is of Unicode String type and variable `imgb` is unsigned int type. They cannot be added.